# ElasticSearch cross-cluster GET by _id

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 3 ElasticSearch 6.3.2 clusters: main, east and west. 'main' is configured to perform cross-cluster searches in east and west. This works well, in that I can perform POST queries to main and obtain data from all 3 clusters. However, I have difficulty performing some GET queries into the remote clusters from main. For example:

http://esmain.example.com:9200/west:error-2019.04/_search

Produces hits; one records has an **_id** of "M2ywYGoBhIcw2VqxQ9FD"

If I try to query just this record via a GET, as in:

http://esmain.example.com:9200/west:error-2019.04/error/M2ywYGoBhIcw2VqxQ9FD

I get:

```
{
  error: {
    root_cause: [
      {
        type: "index_not_found_exception",
        reason: "no such index",
        resource.type: "index_expression",
        resource.id: "west:error-2019.04",
        index_uuid: "_na_",
        index: "west:error-2019.04"
      }
    ],
    type: "index_not_found_exception",
    reason: "no such index",
    resource.type: "index_expression",
    resource.id: "west:error-2019.04",
    index_uuid: "_na_",
    index: "west:error-2019.04"
  },
  status: 404
}
```

If I do the same query via a POST to http://esmain.example.com:9200/west:error-2019.04/_search?ignore_unavailable=true&size=1&timeout=300000ms

with this body:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": 
                { "match": { "_id": "M2ywYGoBhIcw2VqxQ9FD" } }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the correct record, no error. Records residing on the main cluster can be queried via GET no problem (ie, http://esmain.example.com:9200/error-2019.04/error/rf2P2mkBIndI5iSJGgRd), so I'm pretty sure my doc type and syntax are correct.

Although the POST is a work-around, I'd like to be able to provide devs with an easy-to-use URL rather than a POST body, as it makes it easier for them to find the error record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-cluster search is ONLY meant for sending search queries (i.e. on the `_search` endpoint) not GET or DELETE (by ID) queries, which still have to be carried out directly on the corresponding cluster.

One thing you can do is to provide your developers with an easier body-less search query such as the following one that achieves exactly the same purpose as the POST one with the body:

```
GET http://esmain.example.com:9200/west:error-2019.04/_search?q=_id:M2ywYGoBhIcw2VqxQ9FD
```

Comment: Gives me an invalid parameter, but got me on right track. GET http://esmain.example.com:9200/west:error-2019.04/_search?q=_id:M2ywYGoBhIcw2VqxQ9FD did the trick. I didn't know about that q parameter.

Comment: Doh, my bad, I posted my answer too quickly, but yes, I've fixed it.